# Orphan Char appearing when using Sifr3 in Navigation (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, sifr3

I am having an issue implementing Sifr3 on this particular site and it's driving me nuts. 
Hoping someone will be able to help me:

http://client.missmonkee.com/agency-mobile
LOGIN:
client-login
cl1entpassw0rd

Here at the top right you can see the navigation to the site, in FF3 Win 7 / FF & Safari MAC some menu items show 1 char on a seperate line to the rest of the menu item. It looks as if there is a width on the li or something but I'm 100% sure there isnt and the rest of the menu items are OK and display fine.

Something in relation to this might help answer this problem, is that Sifr3 does does not work AT ALL in IE7 WIN. I've checked previous answers to this, being the trailing comma issue but I've triple checked and I do not have any trailing commas.

Can anyone help on this pls?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know much about sifr but ive been using cufon extensivly lately and I've had nothing but success with it. It took me about 2 hours to learn and the output looks great. great cross-browser compatability as well.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: Hey Yeah thanks for that... I actually bit the bullet and went with Cufon last night. The only thing I dont like about it, is the text is not selectable. 

However another guy suggested combining it with css3 @font-face and using the Jquery fontavailable plugin to get even better results. 

Check this: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2009/css-xhtml/combining-cufon-and-font-face/

Thanks for your response.